# How to load csv column values correctly in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, dtype

I want to load a csv file as a dataframe in Python with pd.read_table. This file contains data from 60 parameters at different time points. The ‘Time’ column looks like this in Excel:

[image]

The time should actually be 39.7318, 39.75808 etc. However, when I load the file into Python, it reads the values in the time column as string. I tried adding dtype = np.float in order for the values to be read correctly;

df = pd.read_table(path, delimiter=";", dtype=np.float)

But this results in ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3.975.808'.

Is it possible to define that this column contains values with 5 decimals?

Comment: If the column contains 5 decimals, why the first entry should'nt be 3.97318 ? There is a missing detail in your question. Can you share a reproducible example of your `csv` _as text_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a file `table.txt` that looks like

```
Time;B
397.318;abc
3.975.808;efg
```

you could try

```
df = pd.read_table("table.txt", sep=";")
df["Time"] = (
    df["Time"].str.replace(".", "", regex=False).astype("float").div(100_000)
)
```

to get

```
       Time    B
0   3.97318  abc
1  39.75808  efg
```

You could also use a converter

```py
def to_float(string):
    return float(string.replace(".", "")) / 100_000

df = pd.read_table("table.txt", sep=";", converters={"Time": to_float})
```

but I think the first solution is more efficient.